# Jquery: display div based on the selection from DropDownList

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdownlist (asp.net) and when user change the selection and i want to display the div based on the selected from dropdownlist.

i have code here...

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilter" runat="server" Width="221px">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Date" Value="DATE"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Subject" Value="SUBJECT"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Status" Value="STATUS"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" runat="server" />




    <div id="divDateRangeSearch">
        <div style="float: left">
            <asp:Label ID="lblDateRange" runat="server" Text="Date Range"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <uc1:DatePicker ID="FromDate" runat="server"  />
            <uc1:DatePicker ID="ToDate" runat="server"  />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="divSearchSubject" >
        <div style="float: left">
            <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text="Subject"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Width="225px"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div> 


    <div id="divStatusSearch">
        <div style="float: left">
            <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text="Status" ></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddStatus" runat="server" Width="152px" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Updated:**

```
<div  style="width: 880px; padding-top: 2px; border-bottom: none;
            height: 28px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFilterResultsBy" runat="server" Text="Filter Results by:"></asp:Label>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilter" runat="server" Width="221px">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Date" Value="DATE"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Subject" Value="SUBJECT"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Status" Value="STATUS"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
            &nbsp;
              <div id="div_date"  style="width:250px; display:none;  "  class="sectionrowDate">
                 <div style="float: left">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDateRange" runat="server" Text="Date Range" ></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <uc1:DatePicker ID="FromDate" runat="server"  />
                    <uc1:DatePicker ID="ToDate" runat="server"  />
                    </div>
            </div>

            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#ddlFilter').change(function(){
   var sel = $(this).val();
   if(sel === 'DATE'){
     hideAll();// a function to hide all the divs first
     $('#divDateRangeSearch').show();
   } else if(sel === 'SUBJECT'){
     ///so on...
   }
});
```

Comment: how do you hide?, i try doing this: ('#div_date').hide()  but does not work.

Comment: does not work the show() method and i debug the code and its executing .show() and .hide() but i dont see any change on the screen, any idea?

Comment: Check your id's.. if they are correct, hide and show should work. also check if the if condition is satisfying correct or not

Comment: @Teja: i have updated my code please have a look, i see the problem and its showing but its was on the below the dropdownlist, but what i want is: "dropdownlist --> div_date -- > search button" thanks.

Comment: Move your button code `<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" runat="server" />` to the bottom, I mean after all the div's